# Finding a definite integral of an algebraic fraction

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to find the definite integral $\displaystyle\int_0^4 \frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}} dx$.

I first tried to manipulate the fraction algebraically and did not succeed down that path. I then chose to use the substitution $x=\tan y$ and after a series of manipulations I used a second substitution $u=cost$ and things got worse. I feel I am doing something wrong. I need a hint here.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x^3 = x\cdot x^2$. Now, put $$u = x^2 + 1 \implies du = 2x\,dx \iff \dfrac{du}{2} = x\,dx$$ and $$x^2 = u-1.$$

We can't forget the bounds: you can simply change the bounds from $x = 0 \implies u = 1$ to $x = 4 \implies u = 17$. Then there's no need to back substitute.

That gives you $$\begin{align}\int_0^4 \frac{x^3\,dx}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}} & = \frac 12 \int_1^{17} \frac {(u-1)\,du}{u^{1/2}}\\ \\& = \frac 12 \int_1^{17} \left(u^{1/2} - u^{-1/2}\right)\,du\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you amWhy, that is flawless.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extremely useful (but apparently rarely taught) tactic for handling integrals involving square-roots of quadratic functions known as [Euler substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). The appropriate Euler substitution can convert any integral of an algebraic function of the form $R{(x,\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})}$, where $R$ is a rational function, into just an integral of a pure rational function.

Applying the technique to your problem, we could use the type-I Euler substitution.

$$\sqrt{x^2+1}=-x+t,$$

$$\implies t=x+\sqrt{x^2+1},~x=\frac{t^2-1}{2t},~$$

$$\implies \mathrm{d}x=\frac{t^2+1}{2t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{4}\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{1}^{4+\sqrt{17}}\frac{(t^2-1)^3}{4t^2(t^2+1)}\cdot\frac{t^2+1}{2t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac18\int_{1}^{4+\sqrt{17}}\frac{(t^2-1)^3}{t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t.\\
\end{align}$$

From there, the rest of the problem should be very straightforward, though perhaps algebraically tedious.

Comment: I like this one. You used type 1 Euler substitution, could you link me to where I can find the other types?

Comment: @2good4this The wikipedia link I provided in my answer nicely describes all three types.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular integral, you could try trigonometric substitution.
First substitute $x = \tan t,$
then substitute $\sec t = u.$
You should then have
$$\int_0^\sqrt{17} (u^2 - 1) du.$$

(As a check, Wolfram Alpha evaluates this to the exact same value as the original integral.)

Answer (score 0):

> $\qquad$ *I then chose to use the substitution $x=\tan y$ and after a series of manipulations I used a second substitution $u=\cos t$ and things got worse. I feel I am doing something wrong.*

$x=\tan u~=>~dx=d(\tan u)=\dfrac{du}{\cos^2u}.~$ At the same time, $1+x^2=1+\tan^2u=\dfrac1{\cos^2u}$.

Thus, $~I=\displaystyle\int_0^a\dfrac{\tan^3u}{\bigg(\dfrac1{\cos u}\bigg)}\dfrac{du}{\cos^2u}=\int_0^a\dfrac{\sin^3u}{\cos^4u}du=-\int_0^a\dfrac{1-\cos^2u}{\cos^4u}d(\cos u),~$ which is

trivial. $~$ Now, $a=\arctan4$, and, after letting $t=\cos u$, the upper limit becomes $\cos(\arctan4)$,

which, by definition, is the cosine of the angle whose tangent is $4.~$ So, $\tan a=\dfrac{\sin a}{\cos a}=4.~$ But

$\sin a=\sqrt{1-\cos^2a}.~$ This yields a quadratic equation, whose solution is $\cos a=\dfrac1{\sqrt{17}}$.

---

Alternately, if you are familiar with [hyperbolic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function), let $x=\sinh y.~$ Since $\sinh'y=\cosh y$

and $1+\sinh^2y=\cosh^2y$, you will be left with $\displaystyle\int_0^b\sinh^3y~dy=\int_0^b\Big(\cosh^2y-1\Big)~d(\cosh y)$,

which is also trivial. Here, $b=\sinh^{-1}4$, and, after letting $z=\cosh y$, the new upper limit will be

$\cosh(\sinh^{-1}4)$, which, by its very definition, is the hyperbolic cosine of the arc whose hyperbolic

sine is $4.~$ In other words, $\sinh b=4.~$ But $\cosh^2b-\sinh^2b=1\iff\cosh b=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2b}=$

$=\sqrt{1+4^2}=\sqrt{17}$.

Comment: I hadn't thought that a trigonometric substitution would work here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{4}{x^{3} \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}^{1/2}}\,\dd x}
=\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ 4}x^{2}\,\dd\pars{x^{2} + 1}^{1/2}
\\[5mm]&=\left.x^{2}\pars{x^{2} + 1}^{1/2}\,\right\vert_{\, 0}^{\, 4}\ -\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{4}\pars{x^{2} + 1}^{1/2}\pars{2x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}}}\ =\ 
16\root{17} - \int_{0}^{16}\pars{x + 1}^{1/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=16\root{17} - \left.{2 \over 3}\pars{x + 1}^{3/2}\right\vert_{0}^{16}
=16\root{17} - {2 \over 3}\pars{17^{3/2} - 1}
=\pars{16 - {2 \over 3}\,17}\root{17} + {2 \over 3}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{14\root{17} + 2 \over 3}}
\approx {\tt 19.9078}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice, I hadn't realised I could integrate by parts here.

Comment: @2good4this I'm glad it was useful for you. Thanks.